# VueJS conditional class appended to mandatory class

Tags: vue.js

Not sure how to do this, I remember reading something like the syntax below to make the appended "disabled" string conditional in the class. "form-control" should not be ommitted.

```
<input type="text" :class="{'form-control ':true}, {'disabled' : edit===true}">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just mix two of those (static and dynamic classes), according to [VueJS docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax):

> In addition, the `v-bind:class` directive can also co-exist with the
> plain `class` attribute.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" :class="{disabled: edit}">
```